# how to solve $x^2-y^2=(2n-1)^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $n$ is known,and $x,y,n$ belong to $\mathbb{N}^+$. What is $x$ and $y$? I know there exists a answer, for example,when $n=111$, $x=6161$, $y=6160$, but I do not know if the answer is unique.

Comment: Hint. Look for solutions when $n=2,3,4$ and $8$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Why those numbers specifically?

Comment: Notice that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$. Notice also that the solution is unique if $2n-1$ is a prime number.

Comment: The answer is not generally unique: $41^2 - 40^2 = 15^2-12^2 =9^2$.

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber Several of the other comments hint at where nonuniqueness happens. $15^2$ is interesting because $15$ is the product of two odd primes, so gives lots of nonuniqueness. That's why I suggested $n=8$.

Comment: There are numerous solutions where at least many (infinity) may be calculated based on the answer.

Comment: Liam, I posed an answer for you!

Comment: @Moti Thank you for your help. I cannot vote because of my limited reputation.

Answer (score 0):

My take:

Assuming $a, b$ whole numbers, let replace $x=a^2+b^2$ and $y=2ab$ and we get $2n-1=a^2-b^2$, (or   $2n-1=b^2-a^2$)

The only limitation on $a, b$ is that one is odd and the other even, and $a>b$

Example: a=4, b=3 results x=25, y=24, and n=4